# Confusion About Acid/Bases That Don’t Follow the Arrhenius Definition

Tags: acid-base, ph

I understand that acidity is merely a reflection of how many free hydrogen ions are in water, and basisicity is just a reflection of the number of hydroxide ions, but I don’t understand how this definition holds true for acids and bases that don’t dissociate into hydrogen ions or hydroxide ions.

For example, how is sodium ethoxide, a very strong base, able to have such a high ph (14) if it doesn’t dissociate into hydroxide ions? I get how it’s called a base due to the Bronstead-Lowry definition, but I don’t get how it has such a high pH.

Comment: Sodium ethoxide does not have any pH at all.

Comment: When dissolved in water, shouldn’t it have a pH of 14, though?

Comment: When dissolved in water, it will cease to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When discussing the strength of an acid/base we consider its [dissociation constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant), for bases this is its $K_\mathrm{b}$, or for easier comparison its $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$. pH is a property specific to aqueous solutions of a specific composition / concentration / temperature, not any molecule itself.

A 1 M solution of sodium ethoxide will have a pH of 14 because:

$$\ce{OEt- +H2O\rightarrow HOEt +OH-}$$

I would strongly recommend reading up on [Lewis acid-base theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases), since it provides a more general/useful idea of acidity/basicity. Most reactions are in fact not done in water. Also you may be interested in knowing that it is impossible to have a base stronger than $\ce{NaOH}$ in water due to something called the [leveling effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leveling_effect).